# Slice a number in a file

Tags: python, string, file, slice

I have a number 1215 in the file called Lista.txt.

I want to take the number 12 contained in the line, add 1, and print the result which should be 13.

But I am getting this error:

> Could not convert string to float error.

```
palabra=open('Lista.txt')
print palabra
for i in palabra:
    a = float(i[:2])
    b=a+1
    print b
```

**What is causing this?**

Comment: What is the complete traceback

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CarlosMario\Documents\Deicy\Programación\Test.py", line 7, in <module>
    a = float(i[:2])
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: Are you sure you know what's in `Lista.txt`?

Comment: Yeah, sure there are only 1215 in the first line

Comment: Make sure you don't have any more lines.

Comment: First line? Is that all there is in `Lista.txt`? One line containing `'1215'`? Put the contents of `Lista.txt` in your question to be safe.

Comment: Also include the _entire_ output of your program.

Comment: I just tested this with a file that only contained `1215` and it worked. I'm used python 2.7. Keep in mind it printed a float `13.0`. My guess is his file isn't what he thinks it is.

Comment: Totally sure not even spaces.

Comment: @AustinA, indeed. I'm guessing he has more lines in the file; either non-`float()`able text, or just empty lines.

Comment: I print a and it gives me 12, but i need to operate it.

Comment: @CarlosMartínez, please add to your question the _entire and exact_ contents of `Lista.txt`, and the _entire and exact_ output of your program, traceback and all.

Comment: @CarlosMartínez, I just added character returns (newlines) to my `lista.txt` file and received the same error as you're getting. I'm 100% sure that even though you don't see it, there is atleast one newline character in that file.

Comment: @CarlosMartínez Please try this. `f = open('lista.txt); print f.read()`. I'm almost positive you'll see a `\n` in the output.

Comment: I will create another file. Thanks.

Comment: Another disaster averted through the help of SO'ers.

Comment: Open how? Maybe you mean what you were looking at wasn't saved?

Comment: Yeah, I am making a program to encrypt and decrypt the words by assing them a number, like: L = 12 and A=15...And use the Pitagoras Theorem to encrypt it. And then the reverse process to decrypt it. So maybe I will ask as many questions as I can.

Comment: I know you're probably not planning to use this for something requiring actual security, but just to put it out there; don't write your own crypto code, and *certainly* don't create your own crypto algorithms, for real-world use :). If you want secure crypto, use code/algorithms written/designed by someone who knows what they're doing, and who knows that they know what they're doing. That said, it's fine to do whatever you want for learning purposes :P.

Comment: LOL, yeah is not like i am going to protect a secret mission of my country, but i thought it as a really good exercise to improve my knowledge. Again if any of you can help me, i would be really thankful.

Comment: Just so we're clear @CarlosMartínez, did you get this working?

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much.

Comment: @CarlosMartínez, perhaps you should post an answer yourself and accept it, just so the question is marked as answered.

Comment: @CarlosMartínez, just post an answer explaining the issue and how it was solved, then accept it. Use the answer box at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I did it, but how do I accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was trying to run it and I haven't saved the file, so it caused conflicts, also I looked for spaces in the file, saved, closed and run again the script.